# why does pattern not work for cshtml (razor) asp.net?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my cshtml code for a register page:

```cshtml
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Input.Name"></label>
    <input asp-for="Input.Name" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z{3}]" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

This is the InputModel:

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I submit, I do get an error message from the input model if the length is <3 or >50, however, names are not allowed to contain any special characters or numbers, how should I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to match letters with accents such as à, è, ì, ò, ù?

Comment: You might want a pattern like the following: [A-Za-z]{3,50}

Comment: Now that you address it, I indeed need to allow accents such as those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[RegularExpression]` validation attribute with a regex only allowing letters (`a` through `z` and `A` through `Z`) characters for that.

Example:

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", "Please only enter letters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But if you really want to use the HTML `pattern` attribute on input, you have made a small mistake in your pattern:

```
<input asp-for="Input.Name" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z{3}]" />
```

should be:

```
<input asp-for="Input.Name" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" />
```

Notice the subtle difference in where the `{3}` is located (outside of the square brackets). Refer to this documentation for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to achieve what I need, however the RegularExpression only takes 1 argument, For now I do receive a built-in error message that states: " The field Name must match the regular expression '[A-Za-z]'.", however adding in 'ErrorMessage = "Please only enter letters"' does seem to work. - Dank u zeer!

Comment: You're welcome. What if you try `[RegularExpression(@"pattern", ErrorMessage = "Please only enter letters")]`

Comment: Yes, this works fine! I will try to figure out myself how to allow accents such as Ê.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below attributes for razor pages with asp-for

1. data-val-regex
2. data-val-regex-pattern

Example:

```
data-val-regex="Phone/Mobile number must be 10 digits." data-val-regex-pattern="^(?:.*[0-9]){10,}$"
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you. Been bashing my head against the wall on this. Should be so simple. Make sure you use the underscore in the attribute object if you have a TextBoxFor. Ie: data_val_regex_pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+&#64;[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$"